Как внутри работает функция iter()?
Объект итератор - это не фиксированная конструкция вшитая в питон, а скорее объект построенный по определенным правилам. Правила эти подразумевают, что в iter() будет передаваться, либо объект итератор, либо объект-коллекция. Если это объект итератор, то есть объект, в классе которого описан метод next, определяющий условия выдачи следующего элемента и поднятия исключения StopIteration, когда эти элементы себя исчерпают, то что делает с ним функция iter()?Просто передаёт дальше?. Так же не ясно, что делает функция iter() с объектом-коллекцией.
Приведу пример с циклом for in, который по идее сначала пропускает передаваемый в него объект(после in) через функцию iter(), а затем через функцию next() и останавливает перебор элементов, при вызове StopIteration:
class A:
    def __init__(self, qty):
        self.qty = qty

    def __iter__(self): #Перегружаем оператор взаимодействия с функцией iter(), чтобы он возвращал сам экземпляр т.к. таковой уже является объектом итератором благодаря методу __next__
        return self

    def __next__(self):
            if self.qty > 0 :
                self.qty -= 1
                return '*'
            else : raise StopIteration

a = A(5)
for i in a
    print(i)
#Вывод:
#*
#*
#*
#*
#*

Однако мы можем не использовать метод next:
class A:
    def __init__(self, qty):
        self.qty = qty

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(self.qty)) # Здесь мы как бы возвращаем изначальный функционал функции iter(), применяя его к объекту-коллекции

a = A(5)

for i in a:
    print(i)
#Вывод:
#0
#1
#2
#3
#4

Означает ли это, что любой объект-коллекция по умолчанию несёт в себе метод next, а функция iter() всегда просто возвращает сам объект? Но в таком случае, что означает вывод:
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
c = iter(s)
print(type(c))
#Вывод: <class 'list_iterator'>

Что в действительности сделала функция iter() со списком?

"Означает ли это, что любой объект-коллекция по умолчанию несёт в себе метод next" - нет, только итераторы обязаны реализовывать метод __next__. Итерируемые объекты (коллекции в том числе) обязаны реализовать только __iter__, из которого будет возвращаться итератор (отдельный объект).

Коротко, точно и бесполезно
Если в объекте obj определён __iter__, iter его вызывает.
Если в объекте obj определён __getitem__, iter создаёт обёртку, которая вызывает obj[i] с растущим индексом i, пока тот не выбросит IndexError.
Иначе iter выбрасывает TypeError
Коротко и со смыслом
Если obj – коллекция, obj.__iter__() возвращает итератор, каждый раз новый.
Если obj – итератор, obj.__iter__() возвращает его самого.
Вариант с obj.__getitem__ нужен для обратной совместимости со старым кодом, все нормальные коллекции и итераторы определяют __iter__.
Длинно, с объяснениями
iterable – то, что вы назвали коллекция. Её можно перебирать неограниченное количество раз. Более того, iterable обязана поддерживать одновременный независимый перебор. В примере ниже черепаха и заяц одновременно бегут по одной коллекции с разной скоростью:
a = range(100)  # iterable
hoar = iter(a)
turtle = iter(a)

next(hoar)
print(next(hoar), next(turtle))  # 1 0
next(hoar)
print(next(hoar), next(turtle))  # 3 1
next(hoar)
print(next(hoar), next(turtle))  # 5 2

iterator – поток значений. Это один поток, итератор нельзя размножить, нельзя использовать несколько раз ни одновременно, ни последовательно. В примере ниже заяц и черепаха связаны: вызываете next у зайца, черепаха тоже двигается. Зайцу черепаху не перегнать:
a = iter(range(100))  # iterator
hoar = iter(a)
turtle = iter(a)

next(hoar)
print(next(hoar), next(turtle))  # 1 2
next(hoar)
print(next(hoar), next(turtle))  # 4 5
next(hoar)
print(next(hoar), next(turtle))  # 7 8

Функция iter по iterable строит iterator. Каждый вызов iter создаёт новый итератор. Все эти итераторы обязаны быть независимыми друг от друга.
В iter разрешено передавать iterator. В этом случае она должна вернуть сам этот объект. Она может возвращать и что-нибудь другое, но все эти "другие" должны делить общее состояние.
Зачем итерировать коллекцию много раз? Например, чтобы работал код для обработки всех пар в коллекции:
# a - коллекция
for u in a:
    for v in a:
        print(u, v)

Зачем итератор одноразовый? Чтобы представить данные, которые в принципе нельзя итерировать несколько раз: поток символов из сокета или входного потока. Вы не заставите пользователя вводить всё с начала только потому что вы вызвали iter(sys.stdin).
Чтобы коллекции итерировались, for вызывает iter создавая итератор. Без этого удобства пришлось бы писать for v in iter(a):.
Но и сами итераторы тоже хочется передавать в for. Для этого iter (которая вызывается внутри for) умеет принимать и итераторы тоже и обязана ничего с ними не делать.
Такой дизайн языка, удобно, все к нему привыкли. А вывод отсюда такой: один объект не может быть и коллекцией и итератором. Потому что
вызов iter от коллекции должен создавать независимые итераторы,
вызов iter от итератора должен создавать зависимые итераторы.

Как всегда обстоятельный ответ, правильно, что вашему ответу галку перенесли )

@CrazyElf, спасибо.


<class 'list_iterator'>

Это специальный класс list_iterator, исходник его в варианте интерпретатора CPython можно посмотреть здесь.
С помощью print(dir(c)) можно убедиться, что у него есть методы __iter__ и __next__.
В принципе, тут неоднократно обсуждалось, как корректно реализовывать свой iter() на Python и, если я правильно помню, без использования отдельного класса для этого получалось не очень, именно потому, что нужно сохранять контроль за __next__, а это можно корректно сделать только через новый класс, в котором и будет этот __next__.

А в чём заключается сложность контроля next, когда он находится в самом объекте коллекции? Что возвращает метод iter уже в самом list_iterator? Я имею ввиду, смысл этого просто в удобстве?

@AsLimbo коллекция - это просто набор объектов. Итератор - объект, который может ходить по коллекции. Итератор помнит текущую позицию в коллекции. Сама коллекция - не должна помнить никакую позицию. Она может возвращать итератор, но не должна сама быть итератором. По итератору можно пройти только один раз (после одного прохода каждый следующий вызов next будет кидать StopIteration), а по коллекциям - сколько угодно, потому что каждый новый вызов __iter__ у коллекции создает новый свеженький итератор.

Всё понял, благодарю)
